# How do I implement the sigmoid function in Octave?

Tags: regression, logistic-regression, octave

so given that the sigmoid function is defined as hθ(x) = g(θ^(T)x), how can I implement this funcion in Octave given that g = zeros(size(z)) ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will compute the sigmoid of a scalar, vector or matrix.

```
function g = sigmoid(z)
%   SIGMOID Compute sigmoid function
%   g = SIGMOID(z) computes the sigmoid of z.


% Compute the sigmoid of each value of z (z can be a matrix,
% vector or scalar).

SIGMOID = @(z) 1./(1 + exp(-z));

g = SIGMOID(z);

end
```

Comment: Was using '/' in place of './'. My very very bad.

Comment: You could just use `g = 1 ./ (1 + exp(-z));` instead of creating this `SIGMOID` inside the `sigmoid` function.

Comment: `g= 1./ (1 + exp(-z));` careful about ./ divide had (dot sign) & parentheses of (1 + ...) is mandatory here, I spend mins debugging that.